# Resolve Attribute Based On FK

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm attempting to write an SQL query which returns a list of module numbers and their titles for a university course as well as a list of prerequisites for that module and their titles also. This means the output should look something similar to:

```
Module | Module Title | Prerequisite | Prerequisite Title
C1930  | Computing    | C1100        | Basic Computing
C1930  | Computing    | C1500        | Intermediate Computing
T1350  | Textiles     | T1100        | Sewing
```

The table types are as follows:

Module(**moduleNumber**, moduleName);

Prerequisite(***moduleNumber***, **prerequisiteNumber**);

My issue is with resolving the prerequisteNumber as a moduleName. I can see that it will probably need to be either a subquery or using a JOIN of some sort (INNER JOIN is how I've attempted it), but I can't seem to get it to work.

My query attempts are as follows:

```
SELECT m.moduleNumber as "Module", m.moduleName as "Module Title", p.moduleNumber as "Prerequisite", p.prerequisiteNumber as "Prerequisite Title"
FROM Module m, Prerequisite p
WHERE p.moduleNumber = m.moduleNumber
OR p.prerequisiteNumber = m.moduleNumber
```

and:

```
SELECT m.moduleNumber as "Module", m.moduleName as "Module Title", p.moduleNumber as "Prerequisite"
FROM Module m
INNER JOIN Prerequisite s
ON m.moduleNumber = p.moduleNumber
INNER JOIN
(
     SELECT m.moduleName as "Prerequisite Title"
     FROM Module m, Prerequisite p
     WHERE m.moduleNumber = p.moduleNumber
)
```

Neither of which provide me with the result I want. I feel the first is closer than the second, but I can't seem to progress further on either of them. I've tried searching around but I'm not even sure how to describe this problem, let alone where to begin to look for help.

Thank you for your time.

**EDIT:**

Here is example data for the Module and Prerequisite tables:

Module

```
moduleNumber | moduleName
C1930        | Computing
C1100        | Basic Computing
C1500        | Intermediate Computing
T1350        | Textiles
T1100        | Sewing
```

Prerequisite

```
moduleNumber | prerequisiteNumber
C1930        | C1100
C1930        | C1500
T1350        | T1100
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your prerequisites are in the Module table then perhaps what you are looking for is:

```
SELECT m.moduleNumber as "Module", 
       m.moduleName as "Module Title", 
       p.moduleNumber as "Prerequisite", 
       p.moduleName as "Prerequisite Title"
FROM Module m, Module p, Prerequisite mp
WHERE m.moduleNumber = pm.moduleNumber and p.moduleNumber = pm.prerequisiteNumber
```

using the old SQL or:

```
SELECT m.moduleNumber as "Module", 
       m.moduleName as "Module Title", 
       p.moduleNumber as "Prerequisite", 
       p.moduleName as "Prerequisite Title"
FROM Module m JOIN
     Prerequisite mp ON m.moduleNumber = mp.moduleNumber JOIN
     Module p ON p.moduleNumber = mp.prerequisiteNumber
```

using ANSI SQL.

Comment: Hmm. I can see where you're going with this but it's outputting the same set of data twice - I'll add example data into the original post showing examples.

Comment: Edits have been made - I think this should make the situation clearer - sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: That is the set of data I was assuming. I don't see how it gives a duplicates. I will review.

Comment: Ah - this is now working as intended (using your edit code). Is there any way that this could be written using subqueries? I'm just curious to know if it can be done that way (and if so, how - IN() perhaps?) or if it's simply just a JOIN job.

Comment: I think you want to use this as a hierarchical relationship which seems valid -- Good question.

Comment: You could create a join of (Module m, Prerequisite pm on m.module = pm.prerequisite) and join that to Module on pm.module. Not sure it does you any good but it may be illustrative.